# Cannot use generate_service_last_accessed_details with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to get the last accessed details for an IAM Role.

```
self.client = boto3.client('iam')
resources = self.client.list_roles().get('Roles')

for resource in resources:
    resource_arn = resource.get('Arn')
    gen_last_accessed = self.client.generate_service_last_accessed_details(Arn=resource_arn)
```

The error I receive trying to generate the last accessed details is:

```
'IAM' object has no attribute 'generate_service_last_accessed_details'
```

It doesn't look it's a permissions issue as I've provided the Lambda Role with the required IAM privileges:

```
- iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails
- iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetails
- iam:ListRoles
```

Don't know what else it could be to be honest. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Basically I was running this within AWS Lambda and the Boto3 version pre-packaged does not support `generate_service_last_accessed_details`.

Packaging my own Boto3 with my Lambda function solved this issue.